# Parsing with beautiful soup. Finding strings (numbers) outside span tags

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've managed to parse the following data with beautifulsoup:

```
<span class="price-currency">$</span>200.00</span>, <span class="j-original-price">
<span class="price-currency">$</span>1,000.00</span>, <span class="j-original-price">
<span class="price-currency">$</span>1,300.00</span>, <span class="j-original-price">
<span class="price-currency">$</span>550.00 <span class="price-type price-type--negotiable">Negotiable</span></span>, <span class="j-original-price">
<span class="price-currency">$</span>450.00 <span class="price-type price-type--negotiable">Negotiable</span></span>, <span class="j-original-price">
<span class="price-currency">$</span>50.00 <span class="price-type price-type--negotiable">Negotiable</span></span>, <span class="j-original-price">
```

Now I need to parse the numbers in the middle of each line.
I thought it would use nextSibling but have failed with this.
I also notice that some numbers are followed by close span tags and some numbers are followed by open span tags.

How do I parse these numbers with beautifulsoup?
This is how I got the above data:

```
span = soup("span", { "class" : "price-currency" })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is exactly like you've presented, then getting `.next_sibling` works for me:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: data = """
   ...: <span class="price-currency">$</span>200.00</span>, <span class="j-original-price">
   ...: <span class="price-currency">$</span>1,000.00</span>, <span class="j-original-price">
   ...: <span class="price-currency">$</span>1,300.00</span>, <span class="j-original-price">
   ...: <span class="price-currency">$</span>550.00 <span class="price-type price-type--negotiable">N
   ...: egotiable</span></span>, <span class="j-original-price">
   ...: <span class="price-currency">$</span>450.00 <span class="price-type price-type--negotiable">N
   ...: egotiable</span></span>, <span class="j-original-price">
   ...: <span class="price-currency">$</span>50.00 <span class="price-type price-type--negotiable">Ne
   ...: gotiable</span></span>, <span class="j-original-price">
   ...: """

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [4]: for item in soup("span", {"class": "price-currency"}):
   ...:     print(item.next_sibling)
   ...:     
200.00
1,000.00
1,300.00
550.00 
450.00 
50.00
```

Comment: That worked for me too, thanks!! I was foolishly not iterating through, and a bit confused with my use of next_sibling.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through your data and extract the `.price-currency` tag from `soup`

```
[s.extract() for s in soup("span", {"class":"price-currency"})]
```

And then fetch the required currency value from:

```
list_price = soup("span", {"class":"j-original-price"})
print [pr.text for pr in list_price]
```